# Generate and check download file checksum in Makefile

Tags: makefile, sha256

As part of my `makefile` I need to download and build ZLib. However I want to ensure that when I download ZLib, it is correct by comparing the sha256 of the downloaded .tar.gz against the known correct sha256 value. This need to work on multiple platforms.

I have so far something like the following, however the value of `ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL` always seems to be blank when I compare it with `ZLIB_SHA256`, so my makefile always exits with an error because the checksums are not the same. I am newish to Makefiles, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

```
ZLIB_VER = 1.2.11
ZLIB_SHA256 = c3e5e9fdd5004dcb542feda5ee4f0ff0744628baf8ed2dd5d66f8ca1197cb1a1

SHA256_CMD = sha256sum
ifeq ($(PLATFORM), OS_MACOSX)
        SHA256_CMD = openssl sha256 -r
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM), OS_SOLARIS)
        SHA256_CMD = digest -a sha256
endif

libz.a:
        -rm -rf zlib-$(ZLIB_VER)
        curl -O -L http://zlib.net/zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz
        ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL = $(SHA256_CMD) zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz
        ifneq ($(ZLIB_SHA256), $(ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL))
                $(error zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz checksum mismatch, expected="$(ZLIB_SHA256)" actual="$(ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL)")
        endif
        tar xvzf zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz
        cd zlib-$(ZLIB_VER) && CFLAGS='-fPIC' ./configure --static && make
        cp zlib-$(ZLIB_VER)/libz.a .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A makefile consists of two different programming languages in one file.  Most of the file uses makefile syntax, that make understands and parses.  But the recipes of the rules use shell syntax, which make doesn't try to interpret: it just passes the contents of the recipe to the shell to interpret.

The recipe is the part of the makefile indented with a TAB character, after a target definition.  So in your example above, the target definition is `libz.a:` and all the lines after that which are indented with a TAB, are recipe lines.  They are passed to the shell, not run by `make`.

The recipe is a single block of lines; you cannot intersperse recipe lines with makefile lines.  Once make sees the first non-recipe line, that's the end of the recipe and make starts treating the remaining lines as if they were makefile lines.

Let's look at your rule:

```
libz.a:
        -rm -rf zlib-$(ZLIB_VER)
        curl -O -L http://zlib.net/zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz
```

OK, this is fine: you've created a target `libz.a` and provided two command lines, which are valid shell commands, in your recipe.

```
        ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL = $(SHA256_CMD) zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz
```

OK, now you have problems; this is a *make* variable assignment, not a shell command, but since you've indented it with a TAB make will not interpret it: make will just pass it to the shell.  That's not a valid shell command (in the shell, variable assignments cannot have spaces around the equal sign); this is trying to run a program named literally `ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL` and pass it the arguments `=` and the expansion of the `SHA256_CMD` variable.  Even if this was recognized as a make assignment it wouldn't do what you want since it would just set the value of the variable to the string `openssl sha256 -r zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz`: you want to run that command and set the variable to the output.

Then the next lines:

```
        ifneq ($(ZLIB_SHA256), $(ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL))
                $(error zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz checksum mismatch, expected="$(ZLIB_SHA256)" actual="$(ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL)")
        endif
```

Again, this is wrong because these are *make* commands but you've put them into a recipe which means they'll be passed to the shell, but the shell doesn't know anything about them.

However, they never get the chance to be passed to the shell because the one thing make does with a recipe before it sends it off to the shell is expand all make variables and functions.  So, when make expands this it runs the `error` function and that immediately fails and make never has a chance to try to run the recipe.

This is the tricky part of make.  Maybe I've just confused you with all of the above stuff.

The short, simple answer is: you have to use *shell* commands to perform operations in a recipe.  You cannot use *make* commands (like `ifeq` etc.), and if you want to set variables in a recipe they have to be *shell* variables, not *make* variables.

So, you want something like this, which uses shell syntax not make syntax for the variable assignment and test.

*EDIT* Note your SHA generation command doesn't print just the SHA it also prints the name of the file, so you can't compare them as strings: they'll never be the same.  You need to do something fancier; there are many ways to go about it.  Here I decided to use `case` to do the comparison:

```
libz.a:
        -rm -rf zlib-$(ZLIB_VER)
        curl -O -L http://zlib.net/zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz
        ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL=`$(SHA256_CMD) zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz`; \
        case "$$ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL " in \
            ($(ZLIB_SHA256)\ *) : ok ;; \
            (*) echo zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz checksum mismatch, expected=\"$(ZLIB_SHA256)\" actual=\"$$ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL\"; \
            exit 1 ;; \
        esac
        tar xvzf zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz
        cd zlib-$(ZLIB_VER) && CFLAGS='-fPIC' ./configure --static && $(MAKE)
        cp zlib-$(ZLIB_VER)/libz.a .
```

Note that each logical line in the recipe is passed to a new instance of the shell, so if you want to set a shell variable and test its value you have to combine physical lines into one logical line with the backslash/newline syntax.

Also, when running a sub-make in a recipe you should always use the variable `$(MAKE)` and never use just `make`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation, it has really helper me to understand what is happening here. Unfortunately your solution does not seem to work here, the output I get from make (truncated):

    zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz checksum mismatch, expected="c3e5e9fdd5004dcb542feda5ee4f0ff0744628baf8ed2dd5d66f8ca1197cb1a1" actual="c3e5e9fdd5004dcb542feda5ee4f0ff0744628baf8ed2dd5d66f8ca1197cb1a1 *zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz"make: *** [libz.a] Error 1

Seems the `if` part is still not finding the value of ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL

Comment: That's not the problem.  The problem is that your sha256 command doesn't print just the SHA, it also prints the name of the file.  So the output of that command will never match just the SHA.  Run the command yourself from the command line and see what it prints.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks I changed the sha execution to: `ZLIB_SHA256_ACTUAL=`$(SHA256_CMD) zlib-$(ZLIB_VER).tar.gz | cut -d ' ' -f 1`; \` and that seems to have solved it